# 'NoSuchMethodError' exception with browsermob-proxy 2.1.0-beta4

Tags: nosuchmethoderror, browsermob-proxy

I'm trying to capture traffic from my mobile device using browsermob-proxy 2.1.0-beta4, but I keep getting a `NoSuchMethodError` exception that weirdly enough keeps mentioning Google - `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.net.HostAndPort.fromHost`

Here's my code (without imports):

```
public class BrowserMobProxy {

    @Test
    public void checkConnection() throws JSONException, IOException, InterruptedException {


        SMAPLogger.Info("Connecting to Proxy");
        BrowserMobProxyServer mProxyServer = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
        mProxyServer.start(8888);
//        mProxyServer.setHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT);
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Har har = mProxyServer.getHar();
            if (har != null) {
                for (HarEntry entry : har.getLog().getEntries()) {
                    System.out.print("har");
                    System.out.print(entry.getRequest().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And here's the exception I get:

```
11:39:00.618 [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-4] ERROR org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xf2cbf348, /192.168.100.105:40588 => /192.168.100.101:8888]: Caught an exception on ClientToProxyConnection
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.net.HostAndPort.fromHost(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/common/net/HostAndPort;
    at net.lightbody.bmp.util.BrowserMobHttpUtil.removeMatchingPort(BrowserMobHttpUtil.java:355) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at net.lightbody.bmp.filters.HttpsAwareFiltersAdapter.getFullUrl(HttpsAwareFiltersAdapter.java:87) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at net.lightbody.bmp.filters.BlacklistFilter.clientToProxyRequest(BlacklistFilter.java:37) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at net.lightbody.bmp.filters.BrowserMobHttpFilterChain.clientToProxyRequest(BrowserMobHttpFilterChain.java:65) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection.doReadHTTPInitial(ClientToProxyConnection.java:227) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection.readHTTPInitial(ClientToProxyConnection.java:193) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection.readHTTPInitial(ClientToProxyConnection.java:82) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection.readHTTP(ProxyConnection.java:135) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection.read(ProxyConnection.java:120) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection.channelRead0(ProxyConnection.java:587) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection$RequestReadMonitor.channelRead(ProxyConnection.java:715) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:263) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection$BytesReadMonitor.channelRead(ProxyConnection.java:692) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112) [browsermob-dist-2.1.0-beta-4.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version of Google Guava.

Browsermob relies on Guava version 17+.

If you are using Maven, add the following to your pom-file (or replace the section if you already have a direct Guava dependency):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>17.0</version> <!-- Or something newer like 19.0 -->
    </dependency>
```